# how change the value of one inputfield with 2 different managed beans

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

If i have an inputfield called "monto" with her own bean method called controller:

```
<p:inputText id="monto" value="#{Controller.monto}">
```

this beans add the value of monto in the database.

and i have another inputfield called "capital" , bound to a different bean called "calculate" who return a number after a math calculating method.

```
<p:inputText id="capital" value="#{calculate.capital}">
```

there is some way to change the value of "monto" with the value returned in the bean "calculate"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setter method of monto to set its value so that when the the page is refreshed/submitted (invoke application phase) then the value would be reflect.